# Stochastic Differential Equation after a Change in the Time Parameter

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

How does the stochastic differential equation for a stochastic process change under a change in the time parameter? For example, consider the Bessel Squared Process
$$ dR_t = m \, dt + 2 \sqrt{R_t} \, d\beta_t$$
where $\beta_t$ is some standard Brownian motion. How would one find the stochastic differential equation to, for example, the new process $Z_t := R_{1 - e^{-t}}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the following lemma from Kei Kobayashi's [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.5385) (which is in fact due to [Jacod (1979)](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/BFb0064907)) :

> **Lemma 2.3 :** Let $Z$ be an $(\mathcal F_t)$-semimartingale which is in synchronization with an $(\mathcal F_t)$-time change $(T_t)$. If $H\in L(Z,\mathcal F_t)$, then $H_{T(t-)}\in L(Z\circ T,\mathcal G_t)$, where $\mathcal G_t :=\mathcal F_{T_t}$. Moreover, with probability one, for all $t\ge 0$
> $$\int_0^{T_t} H_s dZ_s = \int_0^t H_{T(s-)}dZ_{T_s} $$

You can check pages 3 and 4 of the paper to get the precise definitions of all the terms introduced, but in practice, this formula will hold if $Z$ is an $\mathcal F_t$-Brownian Motion, $T_t$ is a deterministic and continuous function of $t$ and $H$ is an $\mathcal F_t$-predictable process for which $\int_0^t H_sdZ_s $ is well defined.

Applying the above lemma to the Bessel Squared Process $R_t$ and time change $T(t):=1-e^{-t}$ yields
$$\begin{align}Z_t := R_{T_t}&= Z_0 + mT_t + \int_0^{T_t} 2\sqrt{R_s}d\beta_s\\
&=Z_0 + mT_t + \int_0^{t} 2\sqrt{R_{T(s)}}d\beta_{T(s)}\\
&=Z_0 + mT_t + \int_0^{t} 2\sqrt{Z_s}d\beta_{T(s)}\\
&=Z_0 + \int_0^{t}m T'(s)ds + \int_0^{t} 2\sqrt{Z_s}d\beta_{T(s)}\end{align} $$
Which, you could write in differential form as
$$dZ_t = m\cdot T'(t)dt + 2\sqrt{Z_t}d\beta_{T(t)}\tag1$$

---

**Addendum :** If, like me, it bothers you to integrate against $\beta_{T(t)}$, I found in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1682760/change-of-variable-in-varphis-t-effect-in-mathbbd-w-t) the following theorem from [Oksendal's book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-14394-6). Here I give a version limited to the 1 dimensional case, and where the time change $T_t$ is deterministic. I also skip the technical conditions (measurability, adaptedness...) :

> **Theorem 8.5.7 (simplified version) :** If the time change $T_t$ is a continuously differentiable and non-decreasing function of $t$ such that $T_0=0$, and if the process $H$ is continuous and bounded then
> $$\int_0^{T_t} H_s\,\mathbb{d}\beta_s = \int_0^{t} H_{T(s)}\sqrt{T'(s)}\,\mathbb{d}\beta_s $$

Applying this theorem yields, by proceeding similarly as above, the following (arguably nicer) SDE for the time-changed Bessel Squared Process :
$$dZ_t = m\cdot T'(t)dt + 2\sqrt{T'(t)\cdot Z_t}\ d\beta_t\tag2 $$